# SSH keybased authentication for developers

Tags: linux, ssh, key-pair

I have a linux web server in which I have multiple web sites. I have 5 website programmers now doing the coding for all the sites. How can I provide a key-based authentication for the programmers in such a way that they have access only to /home folder ? They should be able to access only all the files inside /home and able to modify it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are referring to is 'jailing' your users to their home directories. This normally is not done by way of SSH, it's done using chroot.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chroot for more info.